# Why do we numerically minimize functions and not maximize them?

Tags: algorithm, minimize

Why do computers work better with minimizing functions rather than maximizing them? For example, when we apply the maximum likelihood method we have to maximize it and instead of maximizing it, we minimize the negative likelihood. I understand that these are equivalent, but why do we minimize a negative function, instead of just maximizing it?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141087/why-do-we-minimize-the-negative-likelihood-if-it-is-equivalent-to-maximization-o

Comment: Thank you for you answer! But that question does not answer my question. I am asking why, in general, there are many routines to minimize functions, but not so many to maximize functions. Is it because of the convention?

Comment: Calling a function means for the CPU to jump to another place of memory while if the function was inlined it could have saved that jump continue to execute the instructions. This is of course a simplistic picture but maybe that is what you are referring to with minimizing functions.

Comment: I don't see the relation with my question, I am sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just a convention. There is no fundamental difference between a minimisation algorithm and a maximisation algorithm; either can be used for either by negating the objective function as necessary. Standardising on minimisation means you don’t have to keep track of which direction a given optimiser is trying to go in.